# Вопрос по построению сети на Debian 11

Tags: сеть, локальная-сеть

появилась небольшая проблема на учебе. Вот вопрос: Необходимо построить сеть, настроить DHCP, DNS, раздать IP адреса, разрешить маршрутизацию между объектами сети.
Есть шаблон: HV - ISP, ОТ ISP идут 3 пути: ISP-CLIENT, ISP-ROUTER1, ISP-ROUTER2. От роутеров так же идут пути: R1-RCLI1, R2-RCLI2, R2-SRV. Вроде как понятно.
Есть доступ к HV, Так же настроен мосты в файле /etc/network/interfaces. Через VNC VIEWER есть доступ ко всем машинам. Что делать дальше?